# Cells in tableView don't react when pressed

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a tableview that doesn't react when pressed.

When I add:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   print("section: \(indexPath.section)")
   print("row: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```

it first printed all rows and sections in tableview when it first loaded, before I pressed anything. But after I removed that code, and added it again, it don't print anything at all, not even when I press a cell.
Has someone encountered this before?

Comment: Are you sure that you did not add `print` anywhere else in your code?

Comment: Can you show the whole class ? problem might be you're not setting the UITableViewDelegate or you might not be overriding the method, what kind of view is it ? is it a subclass of UITableViewController or UIViewController that has a table as a subview ?

Comment: has the `delegate` been set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a delegate issue. I had somehow set `UITabBarDelegate` in addition to `UITableViewDelegate`
This messed things up. All works well after `UITabBarDelegate` was removed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your compiler does not show maybe you just missing override before.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("section: \(indexPath.section)")
    print("row: \(indexPath.row)")
}
```